# Setting value to enum

Tags: c++, enums

I'm a beginner in C++ so I'm sorry if this is super obvious, but I have an issue with assigning values to an enum. I've declared the enum like so in a header file:

```
 enum face
    {   paramControlHeight = 40,
        paramLabelWidth    = 80,
        paramSliderWidth   = 300
    };
```

And tried assigning an integer. Needless to say it doesn't work:

```
paramControlHeight = 40;//Not assignable
```

After googling about for a while, I tried:

```
using type_of_p=decltype(paramControlHeight);
```

Which as I understand, should yield the type of paramControlHeight, and enable me to use

```
paramControlHeight=static_cast<type_of_p> (40);
```

But I get the same "un-assignable" error

If anyone could point me in the right direction I'd be very grateful

Comment: What do you mean by "assign values to enum"? Do you want to *create a variable of type `face`* and *assign value `40`* to it?

Comment: I want to assign "paramControlHeight" which is inside my enum a different value. So, for example, it starts out as 40, but I would like to change it to 80 later on .

Comment: enums are contant expressions and cannot be changed.

Comment: `paramControlHeight`  is a constant. You assign variables with it: `auto var = paramControlHeight;` You can't assign new values to a constant.

Comment: That's not possible. Enums have set values. You need a variable (e.g. `int paramControlHeight = 40`) to be able to change it.

Comment: You probably want to declare them as `int`s or `unsigned int`s or something like that. `int paramControlHeight = 40;` `int paramLabelWidth = 80;`, etc.

Comment: Okay, enums are constant, duly noted. Thank you everyone for pitching in !

Answer (score 2):

> I want to assign "paramControlHeight" which is inside my enum a different value. So, for example, it starts out as 40, but I would like to change it to 80 later on

You seem to misunderstand what enums are. You seem to expect the enum to behave like this

```
struct face
{   int paramControlHeight = 40;
    int paramLabelWidth    = 80;
    int paramSliderWidth   = 300;
};

face f;                     // create instance
f.paramControlHeight = 40;  // modify member
```

However, an enum is rather like a

```
struct face
{   
    static const int paramControlHeight = 40;
    static const int paramLabelWidth    = 80;
    static const int paramSliderWidth   = 300;
};
```

Now back to your actual enum:

```
enum face
{   paramControlHeight = 40,
    paramLabelWidth    = 80,
    paramSliderWidth   = 300
};
```

Here `paramControlHeight` is an enumerator with the value `40`. You cannot modify it. It is not meant to be modified. It is meant to enumerate. What you can do is:

```
face f{ paramControlHeight };   // create instance of face
f = paramSliderWidth;           // assign a different value to it
```

A more typical enum would be

```
enum face_parts {
    nose = 1,
    eye = 2,
    mouth = 3
};
```

That you could use like this

```
void print_face_part( face_parts fp ){
    if (fp == nose) std::cout << "nose";
    if (fp == eye) std::cout << "eye";
    if (fp == mouth) std::cout << "mouth";
}
```

In simple terms an enum lets you name and group constants. Note that since C++11 there are [scoped enums](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum) that are more flexible and dont introduce the name of the enumerators in the enclosing namespace.

Answer (score 1):

`paramControlHeight`, `paramLabelWidth`, `paramSliderWidth` **are** the values. You can't assign anything to them more than you can assign a value to `42`.